# Cordova BarcodeScan in results.text.slice(0,3) is not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner, phonegap

I have stucked at cordova barcodeScanner plugin in which the result is coming when successful barcode scan is done. I want to slice the result string so i use result.text.slice(0,3). But it is not working.

Here is a code

```
 try{
            cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                    function(result){
                        var Mat =  this.getView().byId("Mat");
                         var bin =  this.getView().byId("bin");
                         var results = result.text;
                       Mat.setValue(results.slice(0,9));
                       bin.setValue(result.slice(29,34));
                              var vMat = Mat.getValue();
                              var vbin = bin.getValue();
                              var odata = this.getView().getModel("tRows").getData();
                              var vdat = odata.results[0];

                              for(var i = 0 ; i < vdat.length ; i ++){
                        if(vMat == odata.results[0][i].material && vbin == odata.results[0][i].temp_str_bin){
                        this.getView().byId("table").setSelectedIndex(i);
                                   }
                     else {
                          MessageBox.show("No Matching Found!");
                           }

                              }

                    }.bind(this),
                    function(error){
                        alert("Not Sanned");
                    });
            }
            catch(err){
                 alert("Camera Error");
            }
   }
```

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: any console log errors?

Comment: Hi Metalik no console error

Comment: show `console.log(result)` output first

Comment: actually cordova barcode scanner is working on mobile devices not for web browsers so i'm unable to print console.log(result)

Comment: It is possible https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/#chrome-remote-debugging , alternative is `alert(result);`

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(result))` please send output of this.

Comment: {"text": "1000106412|mcb 10A pole |EA|AG-162", "format" :"DATA_MATRIX","cancelled" : false}

Comment: response is ok, results.slice is working properly, problem is not related to barcodescanner.

Comment: Can you test with  `substr` instead of `slice` ?

Comment: I have got solution thanks :) @Metalik